# How does Perl store/deal with very large numbers? Should one use a module in lieu of Perl's default handling method?

Tags: perl

I needed to add 50 digit numbers, so I dealt with them as "strings" and wrote my own functions for adding them together.  Afterwards, for the hell of it, I tried this:

```
readFile(shift (@ARGV));

sub readFile
{
    my $file = shift; #contains a bunch of 50-digit numbers
    my $result = 0;

    open (my $inFile, $file);

    while (<$inFile>)
    {
        chomp;
        $result += $_;
    }

    print $result;
}
```

and to my astonishment it worked.  I don't understand.  In every other language I've ever used, you would have to use some sort of special variable to do this.  Does Perl automatically detect that you have a very large number and handle it accordingly?  If so, if one knows ahead of time that they're going to be dealing with very large numbers, is there a Perl module that is more efficient than however Perl deals with them by default?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perl will handle them correctly, *but* as double-precision floating-point values, so your result will not have anywhere near fifty digits of precision. You can use [the `bigint` pragma](http://perldoc.perl.org/bigint.html) to get transparent big-integer handling, however: just tack `use bigint;` into your code. (This obviously won't perform as well as the floating-point math, but it beats having to manipulate strings yourself.)

Comment: Much better than using bigint is focusing its effects on the variables that need it with `use Math::BigInt; my $bigvar = Math::BigInt->new("12345...789");` (and then all operations on $bigvar are overloaded to preserve its bigness)

Comment: In this case, `my $result = Math::BigInt->new('0');`