# From Perl to Java

Tags: java, perl

I am trying to solve some online puzzle finding the largest prime factor of a very large number (*7393913335919140050521110339491123405991919445111971* to be exact). In my search for a solution I stumbled upon this Perl code ([from here](http://thetaoishere.blogspot.nl/2008/05/largest-prime-factor-of-number.html)):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $magic = <number>;

sub largestprimef($);
sub max($$);

print largestprimef($magic);

sub largestprimef($) {
    my $n = shift;

    my $i;
    return largestprimef(max(2, $n/2)) if($n % 2 == 0); 
    my $sn = int( sqrt($n) );

    for ( $i = 3 ; $i <= $sn ; $i += 2 ) {
        if ( $n % $i == 0 ) { last; }
    }
    if ( $i > $sn )    #loop ran over, means the number is prime
    {
        return $n;
    }
    else {
        return max( $i, largestprimef( $n / $i ) );
    }
}

sub max($$) {
    return ( sort { $a <=> $b } (@_) )[1];
}
```

Now that algorithm seemed to work! Small problem with Perl is that it doesn't accept really big numbers. So I rewrote

```
my $magic = <number>;
```

to

```
my $magic = Math::BigInt->new(' <number> ');
```

but that just runs for ages and ages. So I rewrote it to Java (in which I'm a bit more familiar) which resulted in this:

```
static final BigInteger two = new BigInteger( "2" );

public static void main( String[] args ) {
    BigInteger number = new BigInteger( "<number>" );

    System.out.println( goAtIt( number ) );
}

static BigInteger goAtIt( BigInteger prime ) {
    if ( isEven( prime ) )
        return goAtIt( prime.divide( two ).max( two ) );

    BigInteger sqrt = sqrt( prime );
    BigInteger comp = new BigInteger( "3" );

    while (sqrt.compareTo( comp ) > 0) {
        if ( prime.remainder( comp ).equals( BigInteger.ZERO ) )
            break;
        comp = comp.add( two );
    }

    if ( comp.compareTo( sqrt ) > 0 )
        return prime;

    return comp.max( goAtIt( prime.divide( comp ) ) );
}
```

With as auxiliaries (which seem to be fine):

```
static boolean isEven( BigInteger number ) {
    return number.getLowestSetBit() != 0;
}

static BigInteger sqrt( BigInteger n ) {
    BigInteger a = BigInteger.ONE;
    BigInteger b = new BigInteger( n.shiftRight( 5 ).add( new BigInteger( "8" ) ).toString() );
    while (b.compareTo( a ) >= 0) {
        BigInteger mid = new BigInteger( a.add( b ).shiftRight( 1 ).toString() );
        if ( mid.multiply( mid ).compareTo( n ) > 0 )
            b = mid.subtract( BigInteger.ONE );
        else
            a = mid.add( BigInteger.ONE );
    }
    return a.subtract( BigInteger.ONE );
}
```

But my results are always off... and my Perl is not really that good to reverse-engineer the original code. Does anyone have a clue on what I'm missing?

**==UPDATE: problem is (somewhat) solved by workaround**

Comment: Though this is not exactly an answer to your question: IMHO, you might be better off searching for other algorithms for prime factorization, instead of trying to port this one from Perl to Java.

Direct factorization is too slow for such a large number, I guess.

Comment: As a hint: Did you test the rewritten code with small numbers, too?
If it works, then increase the numbers by, say, powers of ten or so, and you will see, how the calculation slows down.

Comment: The perl code uses floats, so there could be truncating problems with your code.  You may have to nudge a value here and there by BigInteger.ONE.

Comment: Thanks for your responses! And ye, I tried small numbers first. They also don't work correctly (tried some in the range of 1234 and 6512344). I think the truncating problem will be the downfall of this program though. Should have used BigDecimal instead. Im gonna retry that first!

Comment: But that also didn't really work :-) I actually recon myself pretty stupid that I didn't think of looking for a java example to this before. It was actually not that hard to find a similar solution here on stackoverflow: https://programmingpraxis.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/primenumbers.pdf ... sorry for that

Comment: Thank you for the link. Did you try it? I wonder how long it takes to factorize your 50-digit number using this algorithm. It would be great if you could let me know.

Comment: Haha, to be honest I gave it up after having it run on one core for half an hour. I briefly considered multithreading this, but then realized that would rather be working around the real problem. Would you have any suggestions on a good alternative? This algorithm already uses Quadratic Sieving... which should be the fastest way right?

Comment: I also kinda google-cheat-search-solved the puzzle though :-)

Comment: A much faster and less memory intensive way than using recursion would be to start by building a list of all the prime numbers up to the number in question. Then work backwards from the big number looking for the first number that divides evenly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### To answer the translation question...

Your Java translation is ***very*** close.  It only has one problem - your `while` loop condition should be `>= 0`, rather than `>0`.  With that amendment, it will work.  As it is - it will output the second largest prime factor in a some cases.

To show this - try it on `1148487369611039` - which has prime factors `104717`, `104723` & `104729`.  Without the correction - it outputs `104723`, with the correction, you get the right answer: `104729`

#### Comment on algorithm

As others have noted in comments - this isn't a particularly fast way to do what you want. In fact that's an understatement - it's very slow.  On my box it took over 3 minutes to find the correct answer (`459905301806642105202622615174502491`)<sup>1</sup>, but it would take a very long time (maybe 500 years, or that kind of order), to prove that number was prime by simply trial dividing every odd number up to its square root (which is what the algorithm does).

You could use all kinds of tricks to get faster, depending how certain you want to be of getting the answer.  One would be to pre-test any candidates for primality - e.g. inserting a test using `BigInteger.isProbablePrime()` with high certainty as a test in `goAtIt()` and returning early if you get a very big prime early in the process.  If you don't like the probabilistic element of that, you could roll your own [Miller-Rabin primality deterministic test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test#Deterministic_variants_of_the_test). You could also build tables of primes and only ever use those in any trial divisions and / or lookups. You might also consider the [Pollard-Strassen algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm)

<sup>1</sup><sub>(I put an output just after the `while` loop in `goAtIt()` to check when it actually found the solution)</sub>

#### Note on Perl big numbers

> Small problem with Perl is that it doesn't accept really big numbers

I think its worse than that because Perl will implicitly [turn the large integer into a double precision floating point](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17016083/838992) if you simply replace

```
my $magic = <number>;
```

with

```
my $magic = 7393913335919140050521110339491123405991919445111971;
```

So - it would give the wrong answer rather than throwing an error as demonstrated on [ideone here](http://ideone.com/eaneoq). Rather nasty, as the algorithm works fine for small numbers and could lull unwary users into a false sense of security if used with larger inputs...